# Вычисления в скобках выполняются не первыми?

Tags: java, синтаксис, инкремент, выражение

Почему вывод в этом коде 1? Такое ощущение, что скобки не дают максимальный приоритет, и операции в них считаются отдельно, но не всегда в первую очередь...

```
class Solution2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3;
        int y = 5;
        System.out.println(y % x * (++x + 0) / 8);

        //Вывод: 1 (а не 0 – если бы в первую очередь сработал инкремент, который в скобках...)

    }
}
```

Comment: порядок выполнения ничем не отличается от того, что используется в школе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что подвыражение записано в скобках не означает, что оно будет выполнено первым. Как известно, выражения в языках программирования вычисляются в [обратной польской нотации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). Если мы запишем выражение `y % x * (++x + 0) / 8` в ОПЗ, то получится:

```
y x % x unary_increment_and_get 0 + * 8 /
```

то есть сначала выполняется взятие остатка от деления, и затем уже инкремент. Более того, если мы посмотрим на байткод метода `public static void main(String[] args)`, то увидим то же самое:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_3
       1: istore_1
       2: iconst_5
       3: istore_2
       4: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       7: iload_2
       8: iload_1
       9: irem // взятие остатка от деления
      10: iinc          1, 1 // инкремент
      13: iload_1
      14: iconst_0
      15: iadd
      16: imul
      17: bipush        8
      19: idiv
      20: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      23: return
```